# AVAudioPlayer issues with playing sound in background

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I am new to programming and I have a small issue which I'm sure should be easily resolved if I just knew where I was going wrong.

I have music playing when my app loads, which loops, and I have 4 buttons on the screen. 3 of them are fine but when I press the play button to play the game the app crashes.

When the app stops it shows a breakpoint beside:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickedPlay {
gameState = kStateRunning;
```

Here is my AudioPlayer code:

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;


if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Where is your audio file located? Did you copy it to the XCode project?

Comment: Yes its in there and plays fine, but when I click to begin the game it crashes.

Comment: What is the crash? What does the error log say? And what is the contents of `gameLoop`?